# To check palindrome in LinkedList -comparing linkedList and Reverse LinkedList.Getting incorrect answer?

Tags: java, linked-list

```
public class CheckPalindromeLL {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Link head=null;

        Link l1=createLinkList1(head);
        Link l2=l1;
        System.out.println("first linklist");
        display(l1);

        System.out.println("reveresed linklist");
        Link rev=reverse(l1);
        Link rev2=rev;
        display(rev2);
        System.out.println("IS PALINDROME");
        compare(l1,rev);
    }

    private static  Link reverse(Link l11) {
        Link l12=l11;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Link nextp;
        Link curr=l12;
        Link prevp=null;
        while(curr!=null)
        {
            nextp=curr.next;
            curr.next=prevp;
            prevp=curr;
            curr=nextp;
        }

        return prevp;
    }

    private static  boolean compare(Link d1, Link d2) {

        boolean flag=true;
        while((d1!=null) && (d2!=null)&& flag)
        {
            if(d1.num!=d2.num)
            { System.out.println("not same ");
                flag=false;
                break;
            } 
            else
            {
                System.out.println("list:"+d1.num);
                System.out.println("rev:"+d2.num);
                System.out.println(" same");
                d1=d1.next;
                d2=d2.next;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("printing flag"+flag);
        return flag;
    }

    private static  Link createLinkList1(Link head) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Link firstlink=head;
        Link newLink = null;

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int x[]={1,2,3,1};
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
            newLink=new Link(x[i]);
            newLink.next=firstlink;
            firstlink=newLink;
        }
        head= firstlink;
        return newLink;
    }

    public static  void display(Link start)
    { 
        Link s1=start;
        while(s1!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(s1.num);
            s1=s1.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comparing `linkedlist` and reverse of `linkedlist` but cannot compare second element.It just check first element of original and reverse `linkedlist` and give answer on the basis of first element only.Am i missing something??

Comment: You only create one `Link` (that is, you have two references to the **same** link).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an ASCII-art depiction of what your list (singular) looks like at each step. I've omitted the superfluous statements and print statements:

```
Link l1=createLinkList1(head);

       l1-+
          |
          V
          1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 -> null

Link rev=reverse(l1);

    rev------------------+
                         |
       l1-+              |
          |              |
          V              V
  null <- 1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 1

compare(l1,rev);
```

You only ever create one list and one set of nodes not two. When you `reverse()` it you rearrange the pointers but leave `l1` pointing to what used to be the first element but is now the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a complete copy of the original list - in reverse order. This should do the trick:

```
private static Link reverse(Link l)
{
    Link result = null;
    while(l != null)
    {
        Link ll = new Link(l.value);
        ll.next = result;
        result = ll;
        l = l.next;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Just as addition: If you have a *doubly* linked list (for the case you are willing to adapt your implementation...), you can easily check for palindromes without creating a reversed copy:

```
private static boolean isPalindrome(Link head, Link tail)
{
    if(head == null)
    {
        return true; // arguable, if empty list is palindrome or not...
    }
    while(head != tail)
    {
        if(head.value != tail.value)
        {
            return false;
        }
        head = head.next;
        if(head == tail) // need this for even number of list elements
        {
            break;
        }
        tail = tail.previous;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**
Just a gimmick: Checking palindrome without duplicating the list (recursive):

```
private static boolean isPalindrome(Link head)
{
    return head == null ? true : isPalindrome(new Link[] { head }, head);
}
private static boolean isPalindrome(Link[] head, Link tail)
{
    if(tail.next != null)
    {
        if(!isPalindrome(head, tail.next))
        {
            return false;
        }
        head[0] = head[0].next;
    }
    return head[0].value == tail.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if a LinkedList is palindrome you can use the following code:

Note that [java.util.LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) is a **doubly** linked list.

```
public class Palindrome<T extends Comparable>{
    public boolean isPalindrome(LinkedList<T> list){
        Iterator<T> iterator = list.iterator();
        Iterator<T> reverseIterator = list.descendingIterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()&&reverseIterator.hasNext()){
            if(!iterator.next().equals(reverseIterator.next())){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```